# How can I save/show the croped image and uncroped image in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, matlab-figure

I am having issue with cropping of image. My task includes an image. I have to crop the image at x,y coordinates, which I have tried and got success.

Now I want to show/save both images, the cropped one and also the image which is being cropped (which will have a subtracted area of cropped part just like subtracting the small cavity from the image).

My Code:

```
B = imread('B1.jpg');
 % figure,imshow(B)
GimageB = rgb2gray(B);
 % figure, imshow(GimageB)

J = imcrop(B,[284 235 95 80]);
  figure, imshow(J)
```

Comment: Show, save or both? show: use `subplot`! save: use `save`! both, do both. You can solve this with google.

Comment: yeah i want to imshow and save the both also.

Comment: actually i want to to get image with the cropped area not the cropped one.

Comment: what? you want the cropped image, not the cropped one?

Comment: let i have 2 images A(size 80x80) and B(size 5x5) now i want to do A-B(subtracting the image B from A with coordinates at center of A).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show the image without the "extracted" area, fill that area with zero!

```
img=rgb2gray(imread('http://weknowyourdreams.com/images/cat/cat-03.jpg'));


img2 = imcrop(img,[500 600 700 800]);

img3=img;
% fill area with zero (note the numbers, compare to imcrop)
img3(500:500+700, 600:600+800)=0;
figure()
imshow(img3)
```

[image]